# Envio PHP Mailer autenticado usando o Gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

Colegas.

Estou tentando enviar um email autenticado pelo PHPMailer usando o GMail dessa forma:

```
include("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail -> SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'emailusado@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'senhadoemail';
```

mas está dando esse erro:

> ﻿2016-04-30 18:24:54  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>   2016-04-30 18:24:54   SMTP connect() failed.

Alguém se o SMTP é esse mesmo?

Comment: Tem algum proxy ou firewall na sua rede?

Comment: Estou usando a rede da minha casa o meu computador tem o próprio Windows Defender da Microsoft e não está usando proxy...

Comment: O que acontece é que o site está em um servidor ( cloud ) e os emails em outro servidor. Estou tentando enviar pelo servidor da cloud, porém tentamos colocar o endereço do servidor ( email ), mas deu erro também. Quando nao autenticamos, as mensagens chegam em qualquer outro email, mas nos emails desse servidor não chegam. Por isso que quero usar o email do GMail para isso, mas também dá erro de SMTP.

Comment: Quando falo rede me refiro a rede que o script rodou, se o problema ocorreu no seu servidor/cloud é lá no firewall deles, você tem que acessar o Cpanel (ou equivalente e verificar se existe bloqueios), se não tiver acesso terá que solicitar com o suporte da empresa

Comment: ah sim... pensei que fosse daqui de casa kkkkk ....entendi... vou dar uma olhada lá....

Comment: Para você autenticar com o SMTP do google, precisa de XOAUTH2 e não mais da senha do usuário. Tem uma alternativa que é autorizar "aplicativos menos seguros", mas o melhor seria fazer a aplicação trabalhar no padrão novo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quase certeza que o google está limitando o acesso ao  email

Acesse a página abaixo e verifique se aplicações menos seguras estão liberadas para a conta em questão

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$mail -> SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

As vezes a porta 587 só funciona com TLS com o Gmail... aconteceu comigo.

Ou

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Para SSL

Além de ter que liberar o seu e-mail na sua conta google.